# Find all solutions to the system of equations:

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Find all solutions to the system of equations:
>
> $$abc^3=24$$ $$ab^3c=54$$ $$a^3bc=6$$

Well by guessing or trial and error, I was able to find

$a=1, b=3,  c=2$

but it said find all solutions, so there is a possbility that there could be other solutions.

If $a=1, b=3,  c=2$ is the only solutions, how would you solve the question more systematically instead of trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

There's one common factor in all of them: $abc$. Isolating it, you have
$$abc=\frac{24}{c^2}=\frac{54}{b^2}=\frac{6}{a^2}$$
Breaking this up, you get
$$\frac{24}{c^2}=\frac{6}{a^2}\to c=2a$$
$$\frac{54}{b^2}=\frac{6}{a^2}\to b=3a$$
You should be able to solve for all three variables now.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: multiply all left and right hand sides:
$$a^5b^5c^5=7776=6^5.$$ This yields $abc=6$. Plugging this into the equations gives $c^2=4,b^2=9,a^2=1$. Hence the solution triples $(a,b,c)$ are $(1,3,2), (1,-3,-2),(-1,3,-2)$ and $(-1,-3,2)$.